# Send multiple mail at a time but other reciepient should not display i.e. other recipient in bcc

Tags: php, email

I want to send mail to multiple user at a time but one user should not see other users addresses i.e. make them in bcc but mail should be sent only once.I have used PHPMailer for that.

```
  $i = 1;
  $emailCount = count($newEmail);
  foreach($newEmail as $emailAddress)
  {
        if($emailCount != $i)
        {
            $phpmail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
        }
        $i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are looking for is:

```
$phpmail->AddBCC($emailAddress);
```

Place this in your loop to add all of the addresses you would like to send to as BCCs. I believe that you do not need to specify an address using AddAddress, rather you can just add many BCCs and send the email that way. See this [other thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?678206-RESOLVED-I-use-phpmailer-and-php-mail%28%29-to-send-bcc-email) for more info.

See this [forum thread](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10314199-Help-with-PHPMailer-and-BCC) for information on including the correct files.

Comment: But when I send mail to person1,others should be in Bcc and they have to get only one mail.

Comment: @user1740124 See my edit on my answer, I clarified it a little bit.

Comment: what about AddAddress() i.e.To field in mail.It will show undisclosed recipients.

Comment: Just don't use AddAddress. You do not need to do that; only use AddBCC (did you read the links I posted in the answer?)

Comment: Well either way, just don't use AddAddress at all. You do not need it. Just use AddBCC.

Comment: What are you trying to show in the "To" field? Your two choices are: either send the emails where the destination addresses are all added as BCCs with no destination address in the TO field (or your own email address in the TO field if you really want something there), or to send each email individually with that address in the TO field

Comment: There is no other solution fir that

Answer (score 0):

As MrGingerbear pointed out, AddBCC is all you need to do.

Each person will only receive one message and they will not be able to see other recipients.

Here is what I have:

```
$recipients = array(
   'recipient1@domain.com' => 'Alex Baker',
   'recipient2@domain.com' => 'Charles Dickens',
);
foreach($recipients as $email => $name)
{
    $mail->AddBCC($email, $name);
}
```

EDIT: Clarifying that AddAddress() is not required, simply used most of the time because you usually include an address in the To: field. However, in your scenario, it would be disadvantageous to do so because then all users would see the address of each user.

EDIT 2: It is not possible, because of the way email is designed, to send only one message, but have the To: field look different to each recipient and also not see the email addresses of the other recipients.

Comment: what about AddAddress() i.e.To field in mail

Comment: @user1740124 You are not required to include the AddAddress() field. If you choose to include that, it will show to all recipients. Some professionals add their own email as the TO: (AddAddress) field but I think it looks unprofessional and I choose to leave it blank.

Comment: Are you seriously just posting what I post on your own answer?

Comment: @MrGingerbear No I am trying to answer the question. It just happens that you type faster than I do. To be honest, I got a notification and just replied to the comment. My sincere apologies, just trying to help.

Comment: @user1740124 There is no way to send only 1 email and have the "To" appear different to each recipient while also hiding the other recipients.